# VM process 20 times slower than before after reinstalling Windows system on real machine

Tags: drivers, performance, vmware, windows-10-v21h2

I'm facing a strange problem and I wonder if someone could give me an idea to solve it:

I have a rather powerful PC under a Windows 10 OS, built on an Intel I9-9900K CPU with 64 Go DDRAM and a not great but rather good video card: a Geforce GTX1650.
In that PC, I have installed VMware 12 with a Win7 virtual machine that I have dedicated to cut video files using VideoRedo (extract movies from .ts files taken from TV records).

Last week, I just have changed my system disk from Samsung EVO 850 1 TeraByte SSD to a new SSD, in aim to double the capacity of my PC's system disk: the new system disk is a Western Digital 2 TB SSD. Then I loaded the last Win10 version from the Microsoft network, called **Windows 10 21H2**, and installed that new version on that brand new SSD .

Then I reinstalled my old **VMWare 12** and restarted my cutting-videos virtual machine, without changing any property to that machine (same 2Gb RAM). And now here's the problem: VideoRedo still works, but **about 20 times slower than before, taking about 10 minutes now for a job that used to take no more than 30 seconds !**

To try and check the origin of that problem, I have installed VideoRedo on the real machine, and it works fine. But I must precise that until last week, with the older 1TB Samsung SSD Device and the older version of Windows 10 on the real machine, the working speed of VideoRedo was about the same when comparing the real and the virtual machine.

So I wonder where that problem may come from, knowing that I have reloaded the various drivers of my motherboard's components, including the video card, and installed them on that new Windows 10 21H2, so the problem seems not to be linked with a driver problem, for otherwise, I think, VideoRedo would also be very slow on the real machine, wouldn't it?

Is it this **21H2** version of Windows 10  that makes VM much slower because of some security constant verification process ? If so, how to turn off this slowing process ? If not, what can it be ?

Thanks anyway if you can help me.

Comment: Are you sure the new SSD is as fast as the old one? Some modern large SSD use quad cell flash technology which only fast in writing when it's cache area is used. Otherwise it can drop speed and get slower than a common HDD.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I realize that I bought this SSD without considering its performances, being quite trustful towards Western Digital. It is a "WD Green SSD", model WDS200T2G0A. Your suggestion makes me want to search for benchmarks about that SSD, to see how good its reputation is. The box says up to 545 MBs in reading, but doesn't mention the writing speed...

Comment: ..But still, my real machine lies on the same SSD and I've just made a new try with VideoRedo after reading your message, and  the speed on that machine is quite fast.

Moreover, the VideoRedo process I have defined reads and writes the video files on a network drive from the file server which is another machine. That configuration hasn't changed for years, so I fear the SSD performance might not be the cause, unless VideoRedo would write a buffer on the local disk, I don't know if it works that way.
Anyway, thank you for your help, any idea being useful.

Answer (score 0):

> Then I reinstalled my old VMWare 12 and restarted my cutting-videos
> virtual machine, without changing any property to that machine (same
> 2Gb RAM). And now here's the problem: VideoRedo still works, but about
> 20 times slower than before, taking about 10 minutes now for a job
> that used to take no more than 30 seconds !

VMware V12 is now several years old.

All else looks OK, so upgrade VMware to V16 and that should work.

Do a full uninstall of VMware and restart before upgrading to the new version.

I have VMware V16 on a Windows 10 Host with fast NVMe SSD and 16 GB of memory and my Virtual Machines are very fast.

Upgrade your machines to V16 hardware level as well.

Make certain that VMs use 1 CPU with 2 cores and no more memory than recommended by VMware.  I generally run machines with 4 GB, but on your machine you could have 6 GB for machines.

Do not give Virtual Machines too many resources so that machines and host can work in harmony.

Comment: Thank you for this advice, but there's still one thing I didn't tell: I first installed VMWare 15 and met that problem. So, I desinstalled it and came back to version 12. And by the way, until last week my machine was quite fast with VMware 12. So, that's why I was wondering if the cause was that 21H2 version of Windows 10, knowing that security issues are more and more significant. By the way, which release of Windows 10 are you using ?

Comment: Windows 10 21H2 most recent as of last update. All is very fast. Also check machine settings as I suggested. Do not forget to uninstall VMware and restart before installing another version.

Comment: Thank you for that information. That shows me the problem is not 21H2, so I'll search for something else. For my virtual machine's parameters, I agree with the points you raised because I've bee using VMWare for quite a long time and I faced the problem you raise in terms of too much or too few RAM on the machine. My Win7 virtual video machine has got one own CPU and 2 Gb. I'm going to try a double CPU and 4 Gb. But still, I think it should work as it is, since it did until last week. Maybe there is a bug in one of my drivers, since I just downloaded them ?

Comment: I have been using VMware since it’s Version 1 and have kept it up to date along with mainstream software.

Comment: Well, I started just a short while after you, in 2000 with version 2, and upgraded to every new version until v8, then changed version only from time to time, but always used many VMachines for different roles, even my domain controllers. VMware is such a powerful concept, provided the implementation works as it should!
By the way, I tried 4Gb and double CPU, but it is still the same. This is a nightmare!

Comment: I have VMware on two machines here and not having any issue with Guest machine speed and using all the ideas I posted.